# Is it possible to perform an inline GROUP BY on a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, inline

Is it possible to perform the following lines in a single atomic query?

```
CREATE TABLE tmp AS 
(
    SELECT fooId, SUM(amount) AS amount 
    FROM foo 
    GROUP BY fooId
);
TRUNCATE TABLE foo;
INSERT INTO foo (SELECT fooId, amount FROM tmp);
DROP TABLE tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to update totals in a table? Try

```
REPLACE INTO foo (fooID, amount) 
SELECT fooID, sum(Amount) FROM foo
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to unaccept your answer. MySQL documentation states: `"Currently, you cannot replace into a table and select from the same table in a subquery."` and: `"Note that unless the table has a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index, using a REPLACE statement makes no sense."` and the point is to group multiple fooIds, so I can't have a PK on it.